# How to put the data entered from a user form to a specific sheet of an excel file?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am stuck at this one. i can't really determine the problem? i have these codes and it seems like its not working. could someone help me debug this one? your answers will be greatly appreciated! thank you! :)

```
Private Sub cmdIn_Click()

    Dim DateToday As Date
    Dim WeekdayToday As String
    Dim Name As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sept 14 - Sept 20")
    ws.Activate 'this will activate the worksheet that you will be working on

    DateToday = DateValue(Now)
    WeekdayToday = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateToday))
    Name = txtNickname.Value

        If Name = jane Then
            Select Case WeekToday
                Case Is = "Sunday"
                   ws.Range("B7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Monday"
                   ws.Range("F7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Tuesday"
                   ws.Range("J7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Wednesday"
                   ws.Range("R7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Thursday"
                   ws.Range("T7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                   'ws.[T7].Value = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Friday"
                   ws.Range("V7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                Case Is = "Saturday"
                   ws.Range("Z7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
          End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you working in VBA or VB.Net? What is the problem exactly? Like is it giving some error message or exception?

Comment: WeekdayToday or WeekToday ?  Do yourself a favor and always use Option Explicit at the top of every module....

Comment: Ok. that is noted. It's WeekdayToday. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sir two problems Select Case WeekToday should be Select Case WeekdayToday and If name = jane should be if name = "jane" see code below is fixed.

```
      Dim DateToday As Date
        Dim WeekdayToday As String
        Dim Name As String

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sept 14 - Sept 20")
        ws.Activate 'this will activate the worksheet that you will be working on

        DateToday = DateValue(Now)
        WeekdayToday = WeekdayName(Weekday(DateToday))
        Name = txtNickname.Value

  'Fixed jane to "jane" 
            If Name = "jane" Then
'Fixed WeedTodays to WeekdayToday.
                Select Case WeekdayToday
                    Case Is = "Sunday"
                       ws.Range("B7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Monday"
                       ws.Range("F7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Tuesday"
                       ws.Range("J7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Wednesday"
                       ws.Range("R7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Thursday"
                       ws.Range("T7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                       'ws.[T7].Value = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Friday"
                       ws.Range("V7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
                    Case Is = "Saturday"
                       ws.Range("Z7") = Val(lblTime.Caption)
              End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```